# Updating Protractor Test Results in Rally

Tags: javascript, protractor, rally, jasmine-node

I want to update test results in rally. I'm currently using the Rally API and have that part working. Where I'm struggling is that in order to update the Test Case I need to capture the ID from the Test Class, this is how I'm currently adding the TC id in the protractor Test Class

```
describe('homepage', function() {
  browser.params.rallyTC = 179339279884;
  it('should perform a search', function() {
    intPage.performSearch('inspector');
    expect(intPage.getResult()).toContain('Result');
  });
});
```

First question would be is there a better way of adding the TC id?
Then from my config.js file I'm handling test failures or passes in order to update the ALM tool.

```
if (result.status !== 'passed') {
  console.log('failed');            
  console.log(browser.params.rallyTC);
}
```

Any recommendations, on how to handle this type of variable capture and result update, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now this is my implementation, in my TestClass I set variables to identify rally specific information like the Project, the User and Test Case id.
Then I created a rally.api.js where I use the rally-node bindings to handle all my API resquests. Finally I created a new Reporter and added it to Jasmine. The reporter is really simple and watches for spec results and calls rally's api with the appropriate values.

```
specDone: function(result) {
        if (result.status !== 'passed') {           
            console.log('failed');  
            rally.createTestResult('Fail');         
        }
        else{           
            console.log('passed');  
            rally.createTestResult('Pass');
        }
    }
```